# How to configure/create custom classpath as common to few of many web applications in jetty

Tags: java, jetty, classpath, classloader

We have multiple web applications packaged as war and deployed in jetty.base of jetty server. We are using `9.4.26.v20200117` version of Jetty. Lets say, `a.war, b.war, c.war and d.war`. These are grouped into two. `Group 1 -> a.war and b.war`, and `Group 2 -> c.war and d.war`. We have external dependency jar files in `jetty.base/lib/ext` and `jetty.base/lib/group2`. Only group 1 webapps are owned by my team in our organization and group 2 are owned by other team,

We have `-module-ext` enabled and hence external libs in `jetty.base/lib/ext` are loaded into the server classpath and `extraClassPath` configuration is used in context xml (c.xml and d.xml) for group 2 webapps to load external libs from `jetty.base/lib/group2`.

The problem here is when I upgrade by external jars in `jetty.base/lib/ext` to its latest version, this is affecting Group 2 webapps since `jetty.base/lib/ext` are loaded into the system classpath and it is visible to all web applications. It has been decided to break this coupling between groups. We (Group 1) couldn't use extraClassPath configuration since we have same instance to be shared across group 1 web applications. One possible way I guess is, create a directory in `jetty.base/lib` (Say, `jetty.base/lib/group1`) and move external jars from `jetty.base/lib/ext` to `jetty.base/lib/group1`, create custom classpath and load external jars from `jetty.base/lib/group1` into it and configure this custom classpath available to only group 1 web applications. Any suggestions on how to achieve this or any other possible solutions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you eliminate the entire need for the external JARs, put them into the WAR files themselves?

Comment: The reason behind we load external jars from outside of webapp is 1. we have common dependencies across webapps, and 2. to reduce the war package size. Point 2 is the actual reason since we faced issues in web app deployment when we hard restart the machine at the course of jetty performing deployment. Hence, moving the dependency libraries to WEB-INF/lib will make us to end up with previously faced problem. Any other possible solution to try?

Answer (score 0):

"common dependencies across webapps" is one of the reasons for why JNDI exists.

"to reduce war package size" is a bogus reason (Jetty has been tested up to 4GB war files, with around 5,000 jars in WEB-INF/lib with over 2,000,000 million entries combined)

**Option 1: Use WAR files properly, eliminate the shared dependencies.**

If you *skip* common shared dependencies you ...

- Improve server startup time.
- Improve deployment time of the webapp.
- Allow for hot deploy to work (you don't wind up locking / pinning the classloaders)
- Memory usage is reduced (you have LESS file descriptors in use when you use traditional war files without shared resources)
- File System I/O is reduced (file locks / contention / etc on the shared jar resources being accessed from multiple classloaders)

**Option 2: Use JNDI properly.**

If you still need shared resources (note I said "resources", not dependencies, not classloaders, etc), then consider setting up the resources via an API and sharing that resource with JNDI.

You would bind the resource to the JNDI location of your choice at the server level, exposing only the API as the usage technique.

Put the API jars (not the implementation jars) in your war files `WEB-INF/lib` of each webapp.

Have the webapp, access the common resource via the JNDI lookup, use that resource via the API.

This will split up the resource and how the various classloaders operate properly.

The server classloader is responsible for the common resource impl.

Each webapp classloader is responsible for its own API jar, accessing the common resource via the JNDI layer.

**Option 3: Drop the entire WebApp classloader isolation and invert the behavior.**

*This option is unlikely to be a good choice considering your description of the problem, just including it here for completeness.*

In your `WebAppContext` you can flip the switch on how the classloader lookup behavior works entirely.   From the Servlet specific way, to the Java specific way.

Use [`WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.28.v20200408/jetty-webapp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.java#L1196-L1203) to use the Java behavior.

This means when your webapp needs a class, it checks the parent classloader first (the server) and then the webapp to load a class.